# String to byte[] c#

Tags: c#, строки, format

Есть код:

```
public static string GetString(byte[] bytesArray)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    for (var i = 0; i < bytesArray.Length; i++)
    {
        result += string.Format("0x{0:x2}", bytesArray[i]);
        if (i != bytesArray.Length - 1)
        {
            result += ", ";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Как выполнить обратное преобразование строки в массив byte[]?

Comment: Никогда не делайте `+=` строковой переменной в цикле!

Comment: @PavelMayorov, никогда не говори «никогда». В чём проблема этого оператора, если в задаче нет строки большого размера?

Comment: @ixSci никогда не говори "никогда" :) Никто не знает, насколько большим может оказаться размер входных данных. И когда написать все правильным образом очень просто - сложение строк в цикле не должно даже рассматриваться.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, а каким другим способом сделать? Чем плох цикл, если я знаю, что на входе 32 байта?

Comment: 32 байта - это уже много. Используйте [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) для циклов или [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) для выражений Linq.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, ок. На будущее запомню. Однако, проблема сейчас не только в этом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо просто взять и сделать все в обратном порядке.

Сначала разрезать строку по разделителям:

```
var parts = str.Split(new[] {", "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Потом создать массив байт и в цикле начать его заполнять:

```
var result = new byte[parts.Length];
for (var i=0; i<parts.Length; i++) {
```

От каждого элемента строки надо откусить первые `0x`:

```
    var part = parts[i];
    if (!part.StartsWith("0x")) throw new FormatException();
    part = part.Substring(2);
```

И привести их к числу

```
    result[i] = byte.Parse(part, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

Comment: Самому откусывать первые 0x не нужно, если воспользоваться методом Convert.ToByte так, как это сделано в моем ответе.

Comment: Да, есть такой способ. Но мне было важнее показать сам процесс "обращения" алгоритма назад, чем навыки поиска по стандартной библиотеке.

Comment: Если уж показывать алгоритм, так надо показать его целиком и без использования методов из "стандартных библиотек". Мне было бы интересно почитать как работают StartsWith и Substring. Если не сложно, то добавьте их в свой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ - использовать имеющиеся средства в виде класса Encoding:

```
string str = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("qwerty");
```

P.S. каюсь, невнимательно читал вопрос. Вашу задачу можно решить например так:

```
var res = str.Split(new[] {", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             .Select(x => Byte.Parse(x.Substring(2)))
             .ToArray();
```

Тут, правда, стоит учесть, что это работает только для строк, которые получены вашим методом. Но при необходимости можно оснастить дополнительными проверками входной строки

Comment: Извиняюсь, но вы вопрос вообще читали?

Comment: Автору как бы hex decode сделать надо. Чем ему кодировка *qwerty* поможет? :)

Comment: Почему вы решили, что `byte.Parse` ["проглотит"](https://ideone.com/HGwT6W) шестнадцатиричное значение с префиксом?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, вот и не проглотил.... Проверено.

Comment: @PavelMayorov а с чего вы решили, что я так решил?

Comment: Ну так проверьте и убедитесь: ваш код не работает.

Comment: @PavelMayorov нет это вы проверьте и убедитесь. Если уж решили  поинспектировать мой код, то хотя бы потрудитесь его скопировать правильно. Префикс у меня отсекается с помощью Substring. Это не идеальный способ (приведенный выше пример с Replace более корректен, но я не стал плагиатить), однако для входных данных из примера топикстартера он работает

Comment: А, да, префикс проглядел. Но код все равно работает неправильно: `byte.Parse("12")` вернет 12, а надо - 18.

Comment: @neo не надо ничего проглатывать, воспользуйтесь методом Convert.ToByte так, как это сделано в моем ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку метод GetString(byte[] bytesArray) возвращает строку примерно в таком формате "0x31, 0x32, 0x33", то для обратного преобразования строки в массив byte[] воспользуйтесь следующим методом

```
public static byte[] GetBytes(string str) 
{
    return str.Split(new[] {',', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)      
              .Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16))
              .ToArray();
}
```